# Find a missing values from a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

Is there a way to search in varchar column.

I got table called x with row named par and data in:

```
150/RXRPR1/18/0020642
150/RXRPR1/18/0020640
150/RXRPR1/18/0020639
151/RXRPR1/18/0020638
151/RXRPR1/18/0020637
151/RXRPR1/18/0020636
151/RXRPR1/18/0020634
```

The row is missing

```
150/RXRPR1/18/0020641
151/RXRPR1/18/0020635
```

How to write a SQL statement to search the table for search the missing data?

The data is of type `varchar` and I have permissions to select only in database

Comment: What are the column names?

Comment: that is only one column and it's paragon

Comment: It is not only SELECT * FROM table WHERE x = '150/RXRPR1/18/0020641' ??

Comment: Do you know in advance which specific row(s) to look for? Or do you expect something that magically understands a pattern in the rows and then tells you where there are gaps in the pattern?

Comment: i got in the table about 100000 rows with that sort of data 
and i want to select that what is missing 
if it was an int that want be a problem but it's varchar(40) type

Comment: and yes I expect something that is gaps in the pattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use classical gaps detection in the right 7 chars on your numbers, partitioned by the left 14 chars. Use LEAD function to find the value of the next record and check is the difference between the current value and next value greater than 1. This will detect the gaps and you can calculate the start and the end of the gap by adding 1 to the current value and subtracting one from the next value. Something like this:

```
declare @t table(col varchar(50))
insert into @t(col) values
('150/RXRPR1/18/0020642'),
('150/RXRPR1/18/0020640'),
('150/RXRPR1/18/0020639'),
('151/RXRPR1/18/0020638'),
('151/RXRPR1/18/0020637'),
('151/RXRPR1/18/0020636'),
('151/RXRPR1/18/0020634')

SELECT
     gapStart = left([current], 14) + right('000000' + cast(cast(right([current], 7) as int) + 1 as varchar(10)), 7)
    ,gapEnd   = left([next], 14) + right('000000' + cast(cast(right([next], 7) as int) - 1 as varchar(10)), 7)
FROM
(
SELECT
    [current] = col
   ,[next]    = LEAD(col) OVER (partition by left(col, 14) ORDER BY col)
FROM @t
) tmp
WHERE cast(right([next], 7) as int) - cast(Right([current], 7) as int) > 1;
```

Comment: Why? The size of the gap doesn't matter with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query:

Please replace  @MINVAL,@MAXVAL with respective values.

```
declare @t table([VALUE] varchar(50))
insert into @t([VALUE]) values
('150/RXRPR1/18/0020642'),
('150/RXRPR1/18/0020640'),
('150/RXRPR1/18/0020639'),
('151/RXRPR1/18/0020638'),
('151/RXRPR1/18/0020637'),
('151/RXRPR1/18/0020636'),
('151/RXRPR1/18/0020634')

DECLARE @MINVAL INT = 20634, 
        @MAXVAL INT = 20642; 

WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT @MINVAL VAL 
         UNION ALL 
         SELECT val + 1 VAL 
         FROM   cte 
         WHERE  val < @MAXVAL) 
SELECT missing 
FROM   (SELECT *, 
               Replace (Lead([VALUE]) OVER ( ORDER BY val)
               , CONVERT (INT, RIGHT (Lead([VALUE]) OVER (ORDER BY val), 7)), 
               val) 
               MISSING 
        FROM   cte 
               LEFT JOIN @t X 
                      ON CONVERT (INT, RIGHT (X.[VALUE], 7)) = cte.val) X 
WHERE  [VALUE] IS NULL OPTION ( MAXRECURSION  10000)
```